wireless keyboard, mice and sometimes wifi drop out for a few seconds then continue losing any work in between
We have six computers in our household and this problem happens to every one with wireless mouse or keyboard.  The device just stops working for 2-10 seconds, then starts working again.  This happens randomly, sometimes perhaps hourly and sometimes up to every 20-30 seconds.  Text typed during this period is lost; mouse movements are lost.  Rarely, the wifi connection is lost too - maybe once a week.
On wired computer keyboards/mice and lap tops this does NOT happen.  Connect a wireless keyboard to the laptop and now it happens.
Take the offending laptop and wireless keyboard to my office and there is no problem.
Is this some form of RF interference?  Is this some form of router issue?  Any suggetions what I look for to fix this or how I find the problem?

certainly sounds like RF interference. does it happen on all devices simultaneously, or are they independent?

Does it happen when someone uses a microwave?

As you state, since the issue occurs only with wireless devices, it is almost certainly due to RFI (radio frequency interference).
You might try finding the source of the RFI, e.g., with 2.4 GHz receiver (e.g., some walkie-talkies, or a software defined radio spectrum analyzer). If it's in your house, add filtering to the device. Since this affects multiple devices, likely in different rooms, it would be a strong signal.
If you live near a source of strong signals, such as an airport (where there are radars and RF altimeters), the only fix might be electromagnetic shielding -- the arduous task of enclosing the house, or at least a room, in a conductive Faraday cage.
